Identify movie with villain face changing scene
I  only remember a plot-important scene.
The scene:
The scene was just a single face of a man that turned from one side to the other whilst being operated on. The operations where done by small knives or scissors and altered the look of his face one or multiple times. The more the face turned the more the man started to scream (either from insanity or pain).
Now the whole point of this scene was to explain (via voice-over) how he altered his appearance many times to fool his enemies and that he could change his entire look but never his eyes (something along those lines was said, can't remember the exact quote though).
Now here are some other details I remember but I'm not 100% sure about.
It was set in Victorian era, definitely pre-modern era.
 - Man in the scene was the bad guy.
 - I watched the movie between 2007-2012 on DVD on a bus, and the film did look pretty recent.
Not a lot to go off on, I already checked Face-off and The Count of Monte Cristo but I couldn't find that particular scene.

What country was it likely from or what language was it in?  Descriptions  or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

@Mytherious Your description has some similarities with Rogue Assassin and "Smokin' Aces" but they're not set in Victorian era.

I'm pretty confident this is Arsene Lupin (2004), a french movie about the famous gentleman thief, set in the Victorian era (or as we say in France, "à la Belle Époque" (around 1900-1914). The scene you are talking about is about the bad guy of the movie, who (spoiler ahead) in fact is Arsene's father, going under multiple surgery to fake his death. I remember the line about "changing his look but never his eyes" from that movie. The scene is near the end.
------> Trailer (in french)


"Distract your opponent ...Remember that and no one will defeat you."

In hindsight this does make so much sense. Given the people in charge of picking the movie at the time. It is indeed the correct one. I verified the answer, sadly I can't upvote yet. thanks alot.

You're welcome! Also, I want to re-watch it now...
